# Combining Export Data From Adobe Form Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, pdf-form

I am working on an adobe form that needs to export data from form fields and import into another separate adobe form.

There are a few form fields that are set up as check boxes that I don't want to be mutually exclusive. for example there are 4 possible contact names, they are 4  separate checkboxes that will import into one single form field in the second adobe form. It's possible that it will be just one contact name, or two, or all 4.

So ideally if the form was filled out like this:

```
contact 1 ☑
contact 2 ☐
contact 3 ☑
contact 4 ☐
```

It should output in the second pdf into a single form field like this:

```
Contact(s): Contact 1, Contact 3
```

I'm sure it's easier with another form field type, but unfortunately I need to figure out how to make it work with checkboxes, if possible.

Thank you!!

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried so far, and share pertinent parts of your code?

Comment: I'm very new to javascript but so far I've tried make a variable for contacts and add each checkbox item to that variable.

    `var contacts = this.getField("contact1");
    contact.push("contact2");
    contact.push("contact3");
    contact.push("contact4");`